# Elements with higher z-index are still positioned below elements with lower z-indices

Tags: css, joomla

I am having a stupid issue with a Joomla Menu Module called Maxi Menu.  Here is a screenshot:

[image]

[Link to website](http://labanepal.com)

The problem seems to be caused because of `z-index`. I have checked using firebug, but haven't been able to found out how the lower menu is finding its way to show up on top.

The interesting fact is that after a menu item is hovered, its z-index is changed to `15000` higher than any other menuitem on the page.

How is it still going under the other menu items with `12000` and similar z-indices?

Firbug display of the z-indices:

[image]

Comment: I see alot of z-index on position:relative; z-index only works on position:absolute.

Comment: @MattCharlton, Yes but the hovering element is absolute and z-indez of 15000. How can other element top that?

Comment: Its actually adding the 15000 to both, as they are both be referenced as level1

Comment: @MattCharlton, I understand what you mean, I see only one element changing its z-index to 15000 at a time. See my update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to the two divs that have z-index 10 and 20.

Z-indexing is calculated relative from the first parent that has a non static position (absolute, relative, fixed).

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a higher `z-index` to the parent `ul` element too, so if you have :

```
<ul class="menu banner_menu maximenuck" style="">
 <li class="maximenuck item184 parent first level1 " style="z-index : 12000;......
```

...then this will fix it

```
.menu.banner_menu.maximenuck {
 z-index: 15000;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh.. nice. Could you please explain, why it is necessary for the parent to have higher z-index irrespective to its child?

Comment: @Starx : long explanation ... you could read [more here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/a-detailed-look-at-the-z-index-css-property/) basically `... an element with a z-index value of 100 will appear underneath an element with a z-index value of 1 if the former element is contained by a positioned parent, and the latter is not.`

Comment: The article you linked was very good. For according to it, the next answer is the correct one. So I am going to accept that, but a +1 to you.